# JavaScript clearTimeout returns undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, settimeout, onkeyup

Can someone please explain to me what is wrong with my code below? I am declaring a public variable and setting it to a setTimeout, and if not null, clearing the timeout before it gets set again. When I try to clear the timeout I get undefined so the timeout continues to run.

```
var usernameCheckTimeout = null;

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#username").on("keyup", function(e){ 
        if($(this).val().length >= 6)
        {
            if(usernameCheckTimeout != null)
            {
                clearTimeout(usernameCheckTimeout);
            }
            usernameCheckTimeout = setTimeout(isUsernameAvailable($(this).val()), 1000);
        }
    });
});

function isUsernameAvailable(username)
{
    $.ajax({
        url : "/account/username-check",
        method : "POST",
        dataType : 'json',
        data : {
            'username' : username
        }
    }).done(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The timeout is being cleared.  The problem is that you are calling your function immediately instead of passing the function to `setTimeout`.

```
setTimeout(isUsernameAvailable($(this).val()), 1000);
```

`isUsernameAvailable($(this).val())` will be called and the result of this call will be passed to `setTimeout`.

You should instead pass a function which calls this function:

EDIT:  As @Mark said, you also need to deal with `this` not being what you expect:

```
var value = $(this).val();

setTimeout(function(){
    isUsernameAvailable(value)
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 3):

You do not need to do the null check also you need to create a closure around `this`, otherwise `this` will refer to not what you think `this` actually is.

```
var usernameCheckTimeout;
$("#username").on("keyup", function (e) {
    if ($(this).val().length >= 6) {
        clearTimeout(usernameCheckTimeout);
        var that = this;
        usernameCheckTimeout = setTimeout(function () {
            isUsernameAvailable($(that).val();
        }, 1000);
    }
});
```

Some [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/8xHKw/) love like usual.

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of issues. The first issue, which is huge, is that you are **executing** `isUsernameAvailable($(this).val())` immediately and passing the return value to `setTimeout` - you need to move this into an anonymous function so it does not execute until the anonymous function is called by the timeout:

```
usernameCheckTimeout = setTimeout(function () {
    isUsernameAvailable($(this).val());
}, 1000);
```

the javascript timeout functions rely on numeric IDs to function. You should avoid testing for `null` or `undefined` or anything else, and instead test for a number:

```
// leave it as undefined
var usernameCheckTimeout;

...

if (typeof usernameCheckTimeout === 'number') {
    clearTimeout(usernameCheckTimeout);
}
```

Comment: Thanks jbabey. Correct answer but just a few minutes later than @James-Montagne